# wine: WINEARCH set to win32 but '/home/koha/.wine' is a 64-bit installation

Tags: wine, 64-bit

I got this message:

```
wine: WINEARCH set to win32 but '/home/me/.wine' is a 64-bit installation.
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: Tell us when this message appears. What have you done to get it?

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you follow https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_create_a_32_bit_wineprefix_on_a_64_bit_system.3F and create a 32bit wineprefix by opening a terminal window and running `WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=path_to_wineprefix winecfg`

Comment: This didn't work for me, I got the same error when running this command, even without an existing directory.

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal; WINEARCH=win64; wine /home/me/.wine/whateverprogram.exe
OR
echo "export WINEPREFIX=~/home/me/.wine" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export WINEARCH=win64" >> ~/.bashrc
reboot

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).